# List of lattice points inside $d$-dimensional sphere

Tags: list-manipulation, lattices

I have a series of functions $f_d$ in $d$ variables and would like compute the sum of each one evaluated at each lattice point within the $d$-sphere of radius $R$; that is, at each point $(x_1,x_2 \dots x_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d:\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2 \dots +x_d^2} \leq R$.

I have no problem evaluating the functions $f_d$ at these points; I think the best way would be to use `Part` within `Sum` on the list of lattice points. **What I am unsure of** is how to generate $P_R$, the list of lattice points not outside the $d$-sphere of radius $R$.

Comment: You could use `CoordinateBoundsArray[]` to generate your lattice points, and then filter them afterward with `Select[]` or `Cases[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method 1: select after building the grid

The cubic lattice with side size $2r$ in $d$-dimensions symmetric wrt origin can be defined as:

```
latt[r_,d_]:=Tuples[Range[-r,r],d]
```

Then your points are selected as:

```
pts[r_,d_]:=Select[latt[r,d],Norm[#]<=r&]
```

Example for 3-sphere:

```
Graphics3D[{Point[pts[10,3]],{Opacity[.2],Sphere[{0,0,0},10]}}]
```

[image]

### Method 2: filter during building the grid

Another way of doing this is to check points not after grid is build, but during the process:

```
sphrPTS[r_,d_]:=
Flatten[Array[If[Norm[{##}]<=r,{##},Nothing]&,1+2Table[r,d],-r],d-1]
```

To test let's see now $2$-sphere:

```
Graphics[Point[sphrPTS[30, 2]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
pts[dim_Integer, num_Integer] := 
 Select[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[Table[{-1, 1}, dim]], num], 
  Norm[#] <= 1 &]
```

Then

```
pts[5,20]
```

(Note that this creates 20 sample points, but some subset are within the unit ball.)

Comment: The OP wants lattice points (i.e. integer-valued coordinates), not random ones.